# Bad Listview Performance on Nexus 4, good on Nexus 7

Tags: android, performance, listview

I am developing an Android application at the moment. This application has to deal with large lists alot (thousands of entries, it's actually a playlist).

To add the possibility to reorder the entries, I use the drag-sort-listview library. Additionally, each row has a ProgressBar in it. This bar is only visible on the current item (so just one for the whole list).
However, I am running into huge performance problems on my Nexus 4 (CM 10.1.2 final), while the performance is good at my Nexus 7 (2012, Stock). I tracked the CPU usage while scrolling the list as fast as I can (without using the fastscroll mechanism. On the Nexus 7, CPU usage stayed below 30%, but on the Nexus 4 it hit 80% and the list was extremely laggy. Logcat output had the line

```
I/Choreographer(639): Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

a few times and the UI felt like it would render with 1fps.

The problem is that I can't imagine the reason for this. I am using the ViewHolder pattern in my adapter. Because of custom fonts, I am also using a font cache.

The getView() Method of my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    PlaylistItem playlistItem = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_playlist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist);
        holder.tv_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        holder.tv_number_in_queue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number_in_queue);
        holder.tv_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        holder.tv_track_length = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_track_length);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        holder.drag_point = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drag_point);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Show Artist and title
    holder.tv_artist.setText(playlistItem.getArtist());
    holder.tv_title.setText(playlistItem.getTitle());

    if (queuedItems.get(position) != null)
        holder.tv_number_in_queue.setText("[" + (queuedItems.get(position) + 1) + "]");
    else
        holder.tv_number_in_queue.setText("");

    //Show track length
    if (playlistItem.getLength() > -1)
        holder.tv_track_length.setText(playlistItem.getLengthInHours());
    else
        holder.tv_track_length.setText("");

    //Show index in playlist
    holder.tv_number.setText(playlistItem.getDisplayNumber());

    // Show the progressbar and set progress if the item is the currently playing one
    if (playlistItem.getIndex() == currentItem) {
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (currentTrackLength > 0) {
            if (holder.progressBar.getMax() != currentTrackLength) {
                holder.progressBar.setMax(currentTrackLength);
            }
            holder.progressBar.setProgress(currentTrackPos);
        } else {
            holder.progressBar.setMax(1);
            holder.progressBar.setProgress(1);
        }
    } else {
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_number;
    TextView tv_title;
    TextView tv_artist;
    TextView tv_track_length;
    TextView tv_number_in_queue;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView drag_point;
}
```

The layout of a single list item:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/playlist_fragment_item_height"
    android:background="?attr/background_playlist_item" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drag_point"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="?attr/drag_sort_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drag_point"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:textColor="?attr/foreground_text_color_secondary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_fragment_title_size" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_number" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_track_length"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="?attr/foreground_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_fragment_title_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_artist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_number_in_queue"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Artist"
            android:textColor="?attr/foreground_text_color_secondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_fragment_artist_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_in_queue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_artist"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/foreground_text_color_secondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_fragment_additional_info_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_track_length"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_title"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/foreground_text_color_secondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_fragment_additional_info_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/playlist_fragment_item_margin_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview:

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    android:id="@+id/list_playlist"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/drag_point"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="1.0"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true">

</com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView>
```

I absolutely ran out of ideas. Logcat did only show 2 or 3 GC calls while scrolling by the way, so I think this won't be the reason.

Any idea welcome! Thank you.

EDIT: Ok now it's getting really weird. Just ran the code on a HTC Desire Z (aka G2... 800Mhz, 512MB RAM) with Android 2.3.5 and Sense... even here it's much smoother than on the Nexus 4?! What is gong on? Could CyanogenMod cause this misbehaviour? I am asking, because I don't want to flash another ROM just because of a suspicion.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Works well on HTC Desire and Nexus 7 but lags on Nexus 4. Did you find any solution? I use View Holder pattern, have tried scrolling cache, animation cache, cache color hint, fast scroll, but it still lags on Nexus 4.

Comment: Hi. No, I haven't found a solution for this issue. I have the feeling it got better with Android 4.4.2, but you can still get the list to stutter when you are scrolling really fast.

Comment: I was testing and playing around and found that in my case, if I don't use setImageResource call, the listview scrolls perfectly. It says in the documentation that it's a ui intensive task, but I get the lag with setImageBitmap and setImageDrawable also. In your case, I think you should try with a flatter view heirarchy. Try with one relative layout with one child view, if that works alright, then the problem could be in the xml.

Comment: Do you have android:hardwareAccelerated = "false" in the application tag in the manifest? If yes, remove it, or set it to true, which is the default for 4.0+. Also, [check this blog post for performance tips.](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study)